# What happens to offline collection data when we close the and re-open the app

Tags: powerapps

What happens to PowerApps offline in-memory(Values saved in the collection variable during offline `Collect(offlineData,{...})`) when we close the PowerApps from Mobile during offline mode and re-open it later.

**Is there a way to keep the offline collection even after exiting the app and re-open it later in offline mode and add more; Finally once the connection is back, sync everything to the data source?**

Answer (score 2):

The blog post https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-offline-apps-with-new-powerapps-capabilities/ outlines how to use functions SaveData and LoadData to store data in the local cache.  The article also shows how to check for connection status to allow syncing data.

Answer (score 0):

If the app closed the collection will be cleared. To keep the data you will need to store it into a datasource. This could be a sharepoint or excel sheet or excel.

To do this you will need to store it using either a button or on the app OnClose Function. the command will be the same.

For Button.  OnSelect = Collection(CollectionName, DataSourceName)
For the App OnClose= Collection(CollectionName, DataSourceName)